# To add a string before and after, if the specific string is matched between patterns using sed in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

**Question**: To add a string before and after, if the specified string is matched between patterns using sed in bash ??

In the below code, I want to add /* one line above **object Host "kali" {**   and add */ to the next line after the occurrence of **}** (**not to the last occurrence of }**).

**This is my code**

```
object Host "linux" {
import "windows"
address = "linux"
groups = ["linux"]
}


object Host "kali" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = [linux ]
}


object Host "windows" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = ["windows" ]
}
```

**This is the expected output:**

```
object Host "linux" {
import "windows"
address = "linux"
groups = ["linux"]
}

/*
object Host "kali" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = [linux ]
}
*/

object Host "windows" {
import "linux"
address = "linux"
groups = ["windows" ]
}

**This is what I tried**


#! /bin/bash
NONE='\033[00m'
RED='\033[01;31m'
GREEN='\033[0;32m'
clear
echo -e  "Enter the names to comment in config file"
cat > comment-file.txt
clear
echo -e "#################################################################################"
echo "Please wait. The names will be commented shortly............"
echo -e "#################################################################################"
echo "Dont press any button, Please hold on...."
while read -r names
do
loc=$(grep -il "object.*Host.*\"$names.*\"" /home/jo/folders/test-sc/*.txt)
if [ -z $loc ]
then
        echo -e " $names$RED No Object definition found $NONE "
else
sed -i '/object Host \"$names.*\" {/ { s,^,/*\n,
    : loop
    /}/ {
        s,$,\n*/,
        p
        d
    }
    N
    b loop
}' "$loc"

  echo -e " $names - $loc -   $GREEN Object host defenition commented $NONE "
fi
done < comment-file.txt
echo -e "#################################################################################"
echo -e "\t\t\t\t Script completed \t\t\t\t"
echo -e "#################################################################################"

rm -rf comment-file.txt
```

**Error**:

No changes had been made in the output file which means /home/jo/folders/test-sc/*.txt

Comment: By seeing your profile came to know that you never selected an answer as a correct one, request you to please give it sometime and when you have some answers for your question then you could select any answer out of all as a correct one, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Comment: Sure will do as advised...@RavinderSingh13

Comment: I just now saw that you haven't added your efforts which you have in order to solve your own problem please add them and I will un-delete my answer then. On SO we encourage users to add their efforts, since we all are here to learn

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After finding `object Host "kali" {`:

1. Prepend `/*\n` to the pattern space
2. If `}` is seen, append `\n*/` to the pattern space, `p`rint and `d`elete
3. Append `N`ext line to the pattern space and loop back to step 2.

```
sed -e '/object Host "kali" {/ {
    s,^,/*\n,
    : loop
    /}/ {
        s,$,\n*/,
        p
        d
    }   
    N
    b loop
}'
```

.... addendum...  To properly pass "$names" to be a part of the sed script, we will need to follow the quoting rules for `sh` ... the idea will be to embedding "$names" into the sed script, and the sed line will look like the following:

```
sed -i -e "/object Host \"$names\" {/ {
    s,^,/*\n,
    : loop
    /}/ {
        s,$,\n*/,
        p
        d
    }   
    N
    b loop
}" "$loc"
```

Comment: I tried and it worked but when trying to pass this in a bash loop it is not working, I tried as above can you comment on this.  
 @Michael

Comment: @Mohamed - it would probably been better to frame this as a separate question... but no problem... what was going on after you integrated the sed script in your larger shell script was about quoting rules... `'[stuff] $foo [stuff]'` makes it so that the shell thinks `$foo` is a literal rather than a variable... We simply change the outer single quotes to double quotes and we are OK. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -e '/object Host "kali"/{i\/*' -e ':a;n;/}/!ba;a\*/' -e '}' file
```

Look for a line containing `object Host "kali"` insert a line before it containing `/*`, read/print further lines until one containing `}` and append the line `*/`.